# Inheriting a class function in C++ : general questions for better understanding and if someone can point out my mistakes

Tags: c++, inheritance

So i'm in the process of learning C++ and trying out a small project. In the meantime i have so many questions but lets say googling helps a bit. To the point : i want a class to be able to use a function from another class, i found similar questions and used what i thought was best fitting for my case but, i still feel like my code or my approach is wrong. Also i didn't achieve exactly what i wanted my code to do. The code that follows is just a sample/copy of my original project including only two classes for testing and to keep things as simple as possible for the reader and myself.

Class1.h:

```
#ifndef CLASS1_H
#define CLASS1_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Class1 {
public:
    Class1();
    Class1(const Class1& orig);
    virtual ~Class1();

    void setPeople(std::string newPeople);
    std::string getPeople();
private:
    std::vector <std::string> people;
};

#endif
```

Class1.cpp

```
#include "Class1.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Class1::Class1() {
}

Class1::Class1(const Class1& orig) {
}

Class1::~Class1() {
}

void Class1::setPeople(string newPeople){
    people.push_back(newPeople);
}
string Class1::getPeople(){
    vector<string>::iterator it = people.begin();
    cout<<*it<<endl;
}
```

Class2.h

```
#ifndef CLASS2_H
#define CLASS2_H
#include "Class1.h"
#include <string>

class Class2:
public Class1 {
public:
    Class2();
    Class2(const Class2& orig);
    virtual ~Class2();

    void setName(std::string newName);
    std::string getName();
private:
    std::string name;
};

#endif
```

Class2.cpp

```
#include "Class1.h"
#include "Class2.h"
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

Class2::Class2() {
}

Class2::Class2(const Class2& orig) {
}

Class2::~Class2() {
}
void Class2::setName(string newName){
    name=newName;
    setPeople(name);
}
string Class2::getName(){

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Class1.h"
#include "Class2.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Class1 one;
    Class2 two;

    two.setName("Random name");
    two.getPeople();

    return 0;
}
```

So everytime i use Class2 function ***setName(string newName)*** i want it to pass the value ***name*** to Class1 function ***setPeople(string newPeople)*** so it stores it to ***vector people*** and then be able to print the results using ***getPeople()***(i know the code in getPeople only prints the first string of the vector). I don't know if my approach is correct but it seems to be working when i call ***two.getPeople()*** in main. BUT shouldn't i be able to use also ***one.getPeople()*** to get exactly the same results? In my case its not working a get just an empty string. So either i have the wrong undertanding of how inheritance works or  something is wrong with my code. I would really appreciate if someone has the time to explain if my approach is correct and why my final goal is not working as intended or what i'm doing wrong and what technique i should use.

Comment: Why do you think `one.getPeople()` should give you the same result? You never added a name to `one`.

Comment: `string Class1::getPeople(){
    vector<string>::iterator it = people.begin();
    cout<<*it<<endl;
}`
Do you think this would work ?

Comment: Do you think that `two` inherits from `one` so `one` should be the instance `two` is affecting?

Comment: @NathanOliver well yes kinda i thought thats how is going to be, so it is just wrong i can't just use one to het the same results ?

Comment: @Nick No you cannot.  `two` has its own instance of `Class1` bundled with it.  The only way to affect that is through `two`.  `one` is its own separate instance and is completely independent from `two`.

Comment: @ThisaruGurugei don't get your questiong, yes its working it is printing out whats inside the vector as i said when i use two.getPeople

Comment: Ok thank you @NathanOliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder why you want to put this into two classes, but i suppose it doesn't really matter if it's a learning excersise.

I usually dont code c++ but c, but i feel like you could have multiple ways of solving this. I'll give you some ideas, and hopefully this will lead you to pick a method you prefer ,or think of your own.

You could:
1) have a global vector which both classes use (usually not reccomended to have globals, but it's possible.)
2) have a class in a class, this way the parent class can access the child class. (you could store the vector in the child and read it from parent perhaps.)
3) make 1 class that has all the stuff in it you need.
4) make the vector public instead of private member so it can be accessed  from main / other objects. (if you use this, make sure you pass a pointer from 1 class to the other's data, this will be more efficient then actually copying the data back and forth between classes)

And there should be countless other ways to solve this.

on another note i see a lot of people using #pragma once instead of the #ifndef HEADER_H #define muck. i use these defines in C, and i'm not 100% sure if #pragma once does exactly the same ,but it might be nice to check out. Saves some typing every time you make a header file :)

(i didn't give code examples, as you stated you want to learn, good luck :D)

Comment: Thank you so much i really appreciate your time ! I think im going to try every single one of them (it is indeed for learning, just random thoughts jumping into my head when i try to think of a project to excersise) ! 
Again thank you very much :)

Comment: its good to see people experimenting like this :) i just made some structs with void function pointers in there to see if i could bind multiple functions with various return values to the same pointer. couple headaches later i feel like i understand pointers a little more. fun fun ^^. if you get stuck on any of the suggested methods let me know, or if something just doesn't work. :) then i can maybe amend my tips if they are not accurate enough